# Why is the first letter repeating on some input field data?

Tags: html, forms

I have first name, last name, and email input fields on a form on my website. I am noticing that on about 2% of users that the first letter is repeated. So for example if someone wanted to write:

> John Smith

What actually is submitted is:

> JJohn SSmith

I am trying to find out if there is any way my programming could be affecting the way this comes through the to DB? I am assuming it is only user error since it doesn't happen all that often, but it does happen often enough to where I would like to see if there is a solution to my problem. I would hope people are smarter than to misspell their own name.

Has anyone experienced this problem and if so, was it due to coding errors or simply user error? If it is simply user error, how can I combat this? Perhaps validation that checks against the double letters and notifies the user of such upon submitting the form? I would love suggestions please.

Comment: Post your code used to processing the input, then it'll be easier to tell. It sounds quite strange though, and I would guess that it is user error.

Comment: what does your server-side code look like?

Comment: although It can be a user error, you shouldn't strip out the double starting characters, you never know what the name could be, do you? and in terms of UX and showing an error, imagine someone's name is really SSmith...